# Why Ruby cross_product returns different value from cross product on paper

Tags: ruby, vector

```
u = [1, -2, 1] # u = i -2j + k
v = [3, 1, -2] # v = 3i + j -2k
```

On paper, when I do a cross product of `u x v`, I get 3i + 5j + 7k which should be [3, 5, 7]

But when I do it on IRB, I get -(u x v)

```
irb(main):081:0> u
=> Vector[1, -2, 1]
irb(main):082:0> v
=> Vector[3, 1, -2]
irb(main):083:0> u.cross_product v
=> Vector[-3, -5, -7]
```

This is the answer for a cross product of v and u, `v x u`.

Does `u.cross_product v` in Ruby mean `v x u`?

I am confused.

Comment: I was confused, too. I discovered this bug on my own yesterday. Apparently, as of 2014 Sep 13, the bug has been fixed in ruby's subversion repository, but the fix has not yet been incorporated into a released version of ruby. See my answer below. DMKE provided useful assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the source of the `cross_product` function ([from here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.0/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Vector.html#method-i-cross_product)):

```
# File matrix.rb, line 1764
def cross_product(v)
  Vector.Raise ErrDimensionMismatch unless size == v.size && v.size == 3
  Vector[ v[1]*@elements[2] - v[2]*@elements[1],
          v[2]*@elements[0] - v[0]*@elements[2],
          v[0]*@elements[1] - v[1]*@elements[0] ]
end
```

It appears from this source that the computation considers `v` to be on the vector on the left side of cross product computation, while the vector on which the method is called is considered to be on the right side. This produces the result that you see, because swapping sides in cross product computation gives you a vector of the same size, but pointing in the opposite direction. Hence, if you switch the call around, you would get the result that you got on paper:

```
v.cross_product u
```

Comment: In the ruby source, the comment above the code quoted by dasblinkenlight mentions that "Vector[1, 0, 0].cross_product Vector[0, 1, 0]   => Vector[0, 0, 1]". So the source code disagrees with its own comment. There is indeed an error, either in the comment or in the code. I think that the comment is in the code.

Answer (score 2):

This is a bug in Ruby's standard library, at least up to and including ruby-2.1.2.

For a vector to appear on the left or on the right in a cross product means something. "A x B" in mathematics should mean the same as "A.cross_product B" in ruby.

[The fix](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9499) is already in ruby's subversion repository and, as DMKE has pointed out in a comment, will likely be a part of ruby-2.1.3.

I noticed this yesterday and filed [a bug report](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=761405) with the Debian maintainer for the ruby package.

Comment: The bug was already filed upstream [#9499](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/9499) and fixed in [r46789](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/72d05366066176f73d7199da67036c4f8778595a), which will either become Ruby 2.1.3 or 2.2.0.

Comment: Thanks, DMKE. I have edited my answer in response to your comment.